# visual studio 2022 for mac cannot create c++ console application

Tags: c++, macos, visual-studio

I am using Visual Studio for Mac 2022, and I am trying to create a C++ console application, does anyone know how to get those templates shows up when I choosing language?

Answer (score 3):

Visual Studio for Mac is an IDE solely for .NET development.

If one looks at the [Visual Studio website](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/mac/), it provides a comparison of the Mac and PC versions of Visual Studio. C++ development is not available for Visual Studio 2022 for Mac.

However, there exist many IDEs that support C++ development on Mac. Apple's very own Xcode allows the creation of C++ projects, as well as Visual Studio Code, a highly extensible code editor. CodeBlocks and CLion also exist as C++ IDEs for macOS.

Comment: Before you start working with C++ in Visual Studio Code (VSC), I wholeheartedly recommend reading through [all of the documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp) (excluding the section on installing mingw since you're on a Mac) and probably a couple tutorials on setting up VSC and wrangling its configuration files. Failure to do so has been the cause of much wailing and gnashing of teeth among the horribly confused.